# Is there a way to find the heritage of my bees?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm using feed the beast and am currently trying to efficiently use the bees added by forestry, extra bees and thaumic bees.

I want to find all possible bee-breeds without looking them up, this however requires you to keep track of anything you breed/found, so you don't just randomly keep breeding in a circle between races.

I don't want to spoil all the different bees by looking them up on a wiki. Is there some in game way of keeping track in what combinations I have tried? Can I find out what kind of bees where the ancestors of a specific bee I end up with? The display in the apiarist chest is not exactly simple to understand. An apiarist database succesfully confused me more then it helped.
For example, I have a couple noble bees, but I have no idea how I got to them.

Is the only possibility that I have keeping a spreadsheet with what races I'm breeding together or is there a better in game way?

Comment: extra bees has a block for that and a hand held version something with encyclopedia (or a play on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple tools that can be used to keep track of bee breeding.

- Apiarist chest : it has a list of the possible mutation for each species with a question mark for unknown mutation
- Apiarist backpack : kind of an apiarist chest but handheld version
- Indexer: you can store an infinity of bee in it, but it does not provides any useful info  IIRC
- Beealyzer: reveals the traits and genes of bees also has a list of know mutation
- Analyzer: machine version of the beealyzer (works for tree too)
- Apiarist database : I don't really know what it is useful for cause it keeps crashing on the current version of FTB (at least on my server)
- A machine version of the apiarist database also exists.

Answer (score 0):

A beealyzer will be able to tell you everything about the bee in question, including its heritage, genes, and abilities

http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=bees:tools:beealyzer

Comment: I'll check tonight that I can do anything usefull with slot IV. It isn't very clear at the least. The genes and abilities on slot I and II are rather clear, slot III just has an image and no way of actually knowing what the things are.

Comment: Slot 4 is basically the heritage screen. It shows all the possible mutations past and future of the bee (that you discovered of course)